# javafx scene builder custom component

Tags: javafx, custom-component, scenebuilder

I would like to use the custom component in the scene builder.

I want to embed a canvas to custom component. so i try to change the canvas of attributes .

canvas code like this:

```
    package test;

    import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
    import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;

    public class DrawCanvas extends Canvas{
        public DrawCanvas() {
            draw();
        }

        private void draw() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double width = getWidth();
            double height = getHeight();
            GraphicsContext gc = getGraphicsContext2D();
            gc.strokeLine(0,0,50,50);
        }
    }
```

Custom Component code like this:

```
    package test;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

    public class Test extends BorderPane{

        public Test() {
            super();
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Test.fxml"));
            fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
            fxmlLoader.setController(this);
            try {
                fxmlLoader.load();
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                throw new RuntimeException(exception);
            }
        }
    }
```

fxml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>


    <fx:root xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" type="javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane">
        <center>
        </center>
    </fx:root>
```

I've tried in this way , but it failed.

```
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>
    <?import org.korecky.myjavafx.fxml10.DrawCanvas?>
    <fx:root xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" type="javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane">
        <center>
            <DrawCanvas ></DrawCanvas>
        </center>
    </fx:root>
```

Please give me advice and tips .

Comment: I haven't tried importing your code into SceneBuilder, but there is a [quick guide on how to import components into SceneBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444698/how-to-create-an-fxml-file-for-an-already-created-new-component-in-java-than-add) (and how to troubleshoot the import process), maybe that might help you or somebody who wishes to answer this question.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is working for me, but you need to create a valid canvas, providing some dimensions, otherwise those will be 0x0. For instance:

```
private void draw() {
    setWidth(50);
    setHeight(50);
    GraphicsContext gc = getGraphicsContext2D();
    gc.strokeLine(0,0,50,50);
}
```

Now you can import your `DrawCanvas` component into SceneBuilder, as @jewelsea suggests, and you'll be able to drag it to your scene:

[image: canvas]

You could add some properties to the class, like `canvasWidth` and `canvasHeight`.

```
public class DrawCanvas extends Canvas {

    private final GraphicsContext gc;

    public DrawCanvas() {
        gc = getGraphicsContext2D();
        draw();
    }

    private void draw() {
        setWidth(canvasWidth.get());
        setHeight(canvasHeight.get());
        gc.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth.get(),canvasHeight.get());
        gc.strokeLine(0,0,canvasWidth.get(),canvasHeight.get());
    }

    private final DoubleProperty canvasWidth = new SimpleDoubleProperty(50){
        @Override
        protected void invalidated() {
            draw();
        }
    };

    public double getCanvasWidth() {
        return canvasWidth.get();
    }

    public void setCanvasWidth(double value) {
        canvasWidth.set(value);
    }

    public DoubleProperty canvasWidthProperty() {
        return canvasWidth;
    }
    private final DoubleProperty canvasHeight = new SimpleDoubleProperty(50){
        @Override
        protected void invalidated() {
            draw();
        }
    };

    public double getCanvasHeight() {
        return canvasHeight.get();
    }

    public void setCanvasHeight(double value) {
        canvasHeight.set(value);
    }

    public DoubleProperty canvasHeightProperty() {
        return canvasHeight;
    }

}
```

This will allow you to set them on the Inspector panel:

[image]

or in your fxml files:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
   <center>
      <DrawCanvas canvasWidth="150" canvasHeight="250" />
   </center>
</fx:root>
```