# netbeans scenebuilder integration custom components

Tags: javafx, fxml, netbeans-8, scenebuilder, gluon

I have a problem with the integration between NetBeans (8.1) and gluon SceneBuilder (8.2.0) using jdk 1.8.0_92-b14.

1. create a maven project with java in src and fxml in resources
2. create a correct custom component according to docs
3. build the project
4. import the jar as library in SceneBuilder
5. open the fxml of the component in SceneBuilder with menu: file / open => OK
6. open the same fxml by double clicking in NetBeans => ClassNotFound
7. open the same fxml by starting SceneBuilder on the commandline with the fxml as argument => ClassNotFound

Can anyone shine a light, or perhaps share a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an FXML file for an already created new component in java than add it to scene builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444698/how-to-create-an-fxml-file-for-an-already-created-new-component-in-java-than-add)

Comment: It is under the attention of gluon-oss, see https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues/64/scenebuilder-fails-to-open-with-custom#comment-29087718