# Having new javaFX class on scene builder

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, graphics, scenebuilder

I'm trying to make a quite complex UI using javaFX scene builder. The UI has lots of objects (e.g. buttons) with similar functionalities and I want to use instances of subclasses of that javaFX classes (e.g. MyButton) that support those functionalities.
*For example I have about 30-40 buttons which all should type "blah blah" in the event of clicking. I'd like to make a subclass of Button named Mybutton which does that and use it's instances instead of adding this functionality to each one of those buttons.*
I've tried to import those classes as a .jar file into scene builder for a couple of times but each time I get this :
[It's all i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1PuY.png)
Is it possible at all to import subclasses of javaFX classes and to use them in scene builder? and if the answer is no what are my other options?

Comment: This is possible. Can you post an outline (remove any specific implementation details) of your MyButton class?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063792/adding-a-custom-component-to-scenebuilder-2-0 Are you placing any of your custom classes in the default package? SceneBuilder will not work with that (and it is bad practice anyway).

Comment: See also: [How to create an FXML file for an already created new component in java than add it to scene builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444698/how-to-create-an-fxml-file-for-an-already-created-new-component-in-java-than-add)