# Creating Custom Control in Jar for Gluon Scene Builder 11.00

Tags: javafx, jar, custom-controls, scenebuilder, gluon

I want to create a custom control in an executable jar file and then use in Gluon Scene Builder 11.00. I need to know how to do this. I tried several forms but my controls not appear when import jar in Scene Builder. I am using IntelliJ Community Edition 2019.2 and Gluon Scene Builder 11.00 and Java 12.0.2. Anyone please that could help me with a little example?

Maven Project.

custom_control.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<fx:root maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="138.0" type="VBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="textField" />
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#doSomething" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="142.0" text="Clck Me" />
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

CustomControl.java

```
package customcontrolexample;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class CustomControl extends VBox {
    @FXML private TextField textField;

    public CustomControl() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
                "custom_control.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }

    public void setText(String value) {
        textProperty().set(value);
    }

    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return textField.textProperty();
    }

    @FXML
    protected void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("The button was clicked!");
    }
}
```

CustomControlExample.java

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CustomControlExample extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        CustomControl customControl = new CustomControl();
        customControl.setText("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(customControl));
        stage.setTitle("Custom Control");
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(200);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>customcontrol</groupId>
    <artifactId>CustomControlExample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>CustomControlExample</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>CustomControlExample</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198563/discussion-on-question-by-gustavo-gregorio-creating-custom-control-in-jar-for-gl).

Answer (score 6):

There are a few things to consider when you want to create a custom control that can be imported with Scene Builder.

**What qualifies as custom control**

There is no documentation about this, but you can have a look at the current [source code in Scene Builder](https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder/blob/master/kit/src/main/java/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/kit/library/util/JarExplorer.java#L128) that explores all the classes in a jar, and finds valid classes as custom controls:

- Classname not starting with `java.`, `javax.`, `javafx.`, 
  `com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.`, `com.javafx.`, `com.gluonhq`.
- Concrete class (not abstract)
- Assignable from `Node`. This is quite important: the class should be a subclass of a JavaFX node, like a container (i.e. extends from `VBox`) or a built-in node (i.e. extends from `Button`).

For all the classes found, then an FXML is built with something like:

```
 <?import your.class.fullname?>
 <your.class.simplename />
```

If that FXML can be loaded by the `FXMLLoader`, then it is a custom control.
Otherwise it is discarded.

**Type of custom control**

There are several approaches on how to build a custom control, but if you are going to use FXML this old [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/custom_control.htm) gives some important clarification on how to use `fx:root` and how to define the controller, like:

```
public class CustomControl extends VBox {

    public CustomControl() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
"custom_control.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
...
}
```

**Java 11 level**

Finally, since Scene Builder 11 runs on Java 11, the jar has to be compiled with support for Java 11.

Using Maven:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
          <source>11</source>
          <target>11</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Before going to Scene Builder, you can try your custom control in a demo project. This will help you find and solve possible issues in advance.

**Scene Builder 11**

Once you have built the control, you can open Scene Builder [11](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download) and import it following the [documentation](https://docs.gluonhq.com/scenebuilder/#_library_manager).

Basically, using the option `Add Library/FXML from file system` and browsing your file system to locate the jar.

Note: there is a [merged PR](https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder/pull/228) that will allow using the build/target directory of a project, instead of requiring a jar.

In case of the posted custom control, you should get this:

[image: custom control]

If the view doesn't show your control, there is an issue that you have to solve first.

Note: there is a pending [PR](https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder/pull/234) that will provide more information when the process fail.

Comment: For additional, information you can also refer to the answer to a related stack overflow question on [How to Import a Component from a JAR into SceneBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444698/how-to-create-an-fxml-file-for-an-already-created-new-component-in-java-than-add)