# Problem importing JavaFx custom UI components to SceneBuilder

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have created some custom UI components in JavaFx, but when I imported the jar to the Scene Builder it says there are no UI components

Comment: Related: [How to create an FXML file for an already created new component in java than add it to scene builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444698/how-to-create-an-fxml-file-for-an-already-created-new-component-in-java-than-add) and [Adding a custom component to SceneBuilder 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063792/adding-a-custom-component-to-scenebuilder-2-0).  Just adding the related question as a comment for other readers, rather than marking a duplicate as the actual issue the user had was a version mismatch (see self-answer to this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem after searching all over the net.

It was a problem of compatibility between the compiler and SceneBuilder.

I was using JDK 14 and JavaFX 14 to compile the components and importing the jar to SceneBuilder 11.

So I installed SceneBuilder 16 and problem solved.

And of course the UI components must meet the standards, extending a Node and all that.

I hope this is useful to you.