# JFoenix library does not have JFXTabPane support in scenebuilder?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder, jfoenix

Why doesn't JFoenix have the `JFXTabPane` in the imported `.jar` in scenebuilder?

[image]

This means when I try to open my `.fxml` file with scenebuilder in intellij it gives me the `.fxml` file is not a FXML document error.

[image]

[image]

Even after importing the entire JFoenix library in scenebuilder I won't be able to use it because it can't open it without the JFXTabPane.

[image]

Comment: yeah there's no JFXTabPane inside the .jar file https://i.imgur.com/YH6tSED.png. I'm using ```jfoenix 8.0.10```. I've also tried changing the import dependency inside my``` .fxml``` file from ```<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTabPane?>``` to ```<?import com.jfoenix.controls.*?>``` but it's still not being detected inside scenebuilder as valid fxml. If I remove the ```<JFXTabPane> ... </JFXTabPane>``` component it works fine in scenebuilder.

Comment: "there's no JFXTabPane inside the .jar" -> There is a JFXTabPane inside the jfoenix 8.0.10 jar file, I downloaded the jar and extracted the files and there was such a file in there. That it doesn't show up in the library catalog for you after you try to import the jfoenix jar into SceneBuilder is a different issue.

Comment: Thanks. jfoenix 9 is displaying the JFXTabPane. One issue though it doesn't open when right clicking the .fxml file in IntelliJ and clicking "Open in scenebuilder" https://i.imgur.com/4qUozvm.png. Nothing happens. Works fine for other .fxml files that do not contain the JFXTabPane

Comment: ```just use a plain TabPane in your FXML document rather than a JFXTabPane.``` okay I will do this

Comment: Replaced relevant comments with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the most recent versions of SceneBuilder (17) and jfoenix (9.0.10) and dragged the jfoenix jar to the library pane in SceneBuilder to import it. The import completed, JFXTabPane was displayed in the library. When I tried to drag a JFXTabPane from the library catalog into a scene, scene builder started behaving oddly (it broke and did not render the scene being built correctly). So it JFXTabPane still doesn't work with SceneBuilder. I advise you file an report with jfoenix to ask them to fix the issue (they have an issue tracker on their github site).

The asker did note in comments that, under the setup they are using:

> jfoenix 9 is displaying the JFXTabPane

That might be due to using a different version of SceneBuilder than the version 17 I used.

If you continue to have issues, just use a plain TabPane in your FXML document rather than a JFXTabPane. I looked at the source and, functionally they are the same, JFXTabPane inherits from TabPane. In your code, create a new JFXTabPane and replace the TabPane injected by scene builder with your new pane (setting the children and properties the same as the fxml), and you should be fine to design in SceneBuilder but still use a JFXTabPane in your actual app. It is a bit of a hack, but not too bad.

There may be similar issues with using other jfoenix controls in SceneBuilder (I don't know, I haven't tried them), but basic jfoenix controls like JFXButton appeared to work in SceneBuilder fine, so perhaps it is on the JFXTabPane which experiences these issues.

For further information on troubleshooting SceneBuilder custom component import, see the following document (though it may not assist in all cases):

- [How to create an FXML file for an already created new component in java than add it to scene builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444698/how-to-create-an-fxml-file-for-an-already-created-new-component-in-java-than-add)

The answer to which features a SceneBuilder import troubleshooting section.