# Why Scene Builder can't find JFXDatePicker library?

Tags: java, javafx

I have faced with one problem, for my project I need to use JFXDatePicker, however I can't find it to use, Here only DatePicker is avaiable but I need exactly JFXDatePicker.
[Scene Builder: search panel enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbr2d.png)

Comment: I don't know what `JFXDatePicker` is.  It is not a [standard JavaFX control](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/package-summary.html).  What is it?  Can you provide a link to the project or documentation?  Why do you think SceneBuilder would know about it?

Comment: I didn’t realize it was JFoenix (some [info on using that in SceneBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69383452/jfoenix-library-does-not-have-jfxtabpane-support-in-scenebuilder/69385828#69385828)).  I do not recommend it. [MaterialFX](https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX) or the vanilla modena JavaFX controls seem superior to me.  See [info on usage in your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71931192/using-materialfx-in-intellij/71931282#71931282). Import into SceneBuilder is similar, you import the MaterialFX jar into the SceneBuilder tool.

Answer (score 1):

JFXDatePicker is from an external library. Probably from JFoenix. In order to use that in SceneBuilder you have to import that external library in SB. This [Adding a custom component to SceneBuilder 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063792/adding-a-custom-component-to-scenebuilder-2-0) may be helpful.